What is the translation of a code monkey in French?
From nordvpn.com:

Code monkey is a slang term for a programmer or developer who is seen as someone who writes code quickly and without much thought or creativity.

What is the translation of a code monkey in French? Google Translate didn't translate it.

"Copie-colleur de code", "gerbeur de code" will be understood everywhere. Also, "mangeur de quiche" (cuz real programmers don't eat quiche) might be spot on; or not. Once more, hard to tell w/out the proper context.

"mangeur de quiche" - connaissais pas :-)

Pierre Brassau ?

@Obie2.0 LLMs are the Pierre Brassau of SO.

Ironically, you may call him "champion du copier-coller".

@FrançoisJurain on pourrais aussi tenter "photocopieur de stackoverflow" (même si la photocop, ça fait un peu XXeme siècle).

@FrançoisJurain: et pourquoi les vrais programmeurs ne mangeraient-ils pas de quiche?

@PierrePaquette à cause d'une parodie célèbre, y compris chez les informaticiens français: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Programmers_Don%27t_Use_Pascal ; alors que l'original Real Men don't eat Quiche est passé complètement inaperçu ici, me semble-t-il. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Men_Don%27t_Eat_Quiche

@FrançoisJurain C'est vraiment niche. Même parmi les programmeurs, à mon avis, ça ne sera pas universellement compris. Comme Pierre Brasseau, d'ailleurs.

@Frank ben oui, c'est ça les traductions qd on n'a pas une phrase autour pour évaluer le contexte: total loterie.

@FrançoisJurain Le "vraiment niche", c'est l'histoire de la quiche. Sinon pisseur de code, c'est très bien.

@Frank cela dit, les VRAIS programmeurs comprennent ce qu'est un mangeur de quiche sans même qu'on leur explique. C'est même à ça qu'on les reconnaît.

Les vrais programmeurs disent "ouiche" et non "quiche". Question de classe.

Je proposerais :

pisseur de code

Le terme n'est pas très répandu (on le trouve dans google cependant), mais il correspond à une expression très courante chez les programmeurs : "pisser du code". ce qui signifie : taper au kilomètre du code de faible qualité.

Oui, pisser du code.

On trouve « chieur d'encre » aussi,  dans le même registre et le même esprit …

@LPH Je crains que personne n'ait jamais employé cette expression à propos de développeurs de logiciels. Ces derniers n'ont de toute façon jamais beaucoup utilisé d'encre.

@jlliagre Seulement une remarque sur la similarité des termes (et il ne s'agit plus d'écriture, ce n'est que de l'encre).

@LPH Oui, j'avais bien compris la proximité scatologique. Une heure avant ton commentaire, j'ai même inventé une expression proche de celle-ci, mais plus pertinente vu le contexte de la question : Ouais, j'ai toujours eu horreur de cette expression. Pourquoi pas chieurs de bugs pendant qu'on y est ;-) chat

"pisseur de code" est une expression qui est dans mon langage courant de développeur. Non pas que je m'en serve souvent, mais je la comprends tout à fait et c'est les mots que j'emploierais pour parler de l'idée décrite par OP. Pour moi c'est une traduction idéale.

@zdimension dans toute ma carrière professionelle dans l'informatique je n'ai jamais entendu le terme de "pisseur de code", très compréhensible car dérivé de "pisser du code" parfois utilisé familièrement.

@Graffito Tu as eu une bonne carrière à l'abri de ce phénomène.

Aussi: pisser de la ligne.

@jlliagre un (mauvais) journaliste peut aussi pisser de la ligne, donc si tu ne précises pas ligne de code... (ou alors que tu es spot on ds le contexte) ça peut ne pas être clair. On peut pisser des tas de trucs, des notes ...

@None Oui, bien sûr, dans le contexte.

Wiktionary also lists "pisseur de code" as the translation for "code monkey" (expand the Translations section at the bottom)

Pondre du code is also a common expression
